# Convert dataframe type from string to datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I have a column in my dataframe with the format `20110604-20:00` and want to convert it to datetime using :

```
data['datetime'] =  pd.to_datetime(data['datetime'] , format='%Y%m%d-%H:%M')
```

but it keeps telling me :

> ValueError: time data 'datetime_utc' does not match format '%Y%m%d-%H:%M' (match)

so what is wrong with the format?

Comment: Why do you have `scikit-learn` and `sklearn-pandas` tags apart from you presumably imported `sklearn` into your code?

Comment: What if you omit the "format", and just use `pd.to_datetime`? My guess is you either have missing data or inconsistent datetime string formats within that column

Comment: when I changed it to the following it worked but I don't understand why!!                                                           data_1=data[1::]
data_1['datetime'] =  pd.to_datetime(data_1['datetime'] , format='%Y%m%d-%H:%M')

Comment: I just got it. This is because of the first row which is the header.

Comment: I'm not aware of the `to_datetime` function. where is it from?

Comment: It's related to pandas ... pandas.to_datetime(*args, **kwargs)
Convert argument to datetime. check this link http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html